# Python: np.loadtxt, read multiple files

Tags: python, numpy

I have managed to get loadtxt to read in a single file, but now I want it to read in a bunch of files off a .list file I have. I tried throwing it in a for loop, but I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone help please?

`[row1, row2, row3] = np.loadtxt("data.fits",unpack=True,skiprows=1)`

And I want something like

```
for i in range(0,len(array)):
   [row1, row2, row3] = np.loadtxt("list.list[i]",unpack=True,skiprows=1)
   DO THINGS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(array)):
   [row1, row2, row3] = np.loadtxt(list.list[i],unpack=True,skiprows=1)
```

Additionally:

```
filelist=['file1','file2']
for file in filelist:
    [row1, row2, row3] = np.loadtxt(file,unpack=True,skiprows=1)
    #Do Stuff
```

I believe the quotation marks is messing with you. Also you do not need the 0 in range.

If this doesnt work can you paste what list.list is and array?

Comment: array is just the amount of files I have, and list.list is a list of the files it has to read.

so like:
    `data1.fits
    data2.fits
    data3.fits
    data6.fits
    data8.fits`
(With pagebreaks between the files)

Answer (score 0):

```
import fileinput
data = fileinput.input(['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'])
```

Then use that...

Comment: @Coolcrab could you elaborate further please?